# Adding metadata to jQuery UI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm writing a messaging application that uses jQuery UI autocomplete in the "send" field. I have it all working fine, but I need to attach bits of metadata, like a user id, to the items.

When the item is selected, I plan on adding a hidden input with the user id, like so: `<input type="hidden" name="to[]" value="4" />` Adding one for each user selected. Then when the form is submitted, this data will be sent through to a php script, where I can send messages to each user.

I'm just wondering if anything like this is possible, if not, what might be the best way to get around it? Or, is there a better way of doing it than what I'm thinking?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track!

The autocomplete widget is built to handle situations like this. As long as items in your `source` have a `value` property (and optionally a `label` property), the widget will render the options correctly.

So you have two options. You can provide the `label` and `value` property and create your hidden `input` elements with the `value` property upon the `select` event, or use your own attribute. It's easier to see with an example:

```
var users = [
    { label: 'Jon', value: 1 },
    { label: 'Jeff', value: 2 },
    { label: 'Marc', value: 3 },
    { label: 'Josh', value: 4 },
    { label: 'Andrew', value: 5}
];

$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: users,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("body").append("<input type='text' value='" + ui.item.value + "'/>");
    }
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/EYQLV/1/

You could just as easily use `ui.item.id` if each item in your source contained that property.